# mb_detect_encoding(); mysqli extension is missing

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I installed  Apache 2.4.9 with PHP 5.4.30 and MySQL 5.7 working perfectly. When I was trying to run phpMyAdmin 4.2.5 I had an error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()

I uncommented   mbstring in `php.ini`, restarted the server, computer, my wife and my dog. The result was the same:

> undefined function mb_detect_encoding()

I reinstalled PHP to 5.3.28 version. No way. I reinstalled phpMyAdmin to 3.5.6 version (that is working well on my old computer). Now I have:

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>
> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your
>   PHP configuration.

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
```

Resolved:
In httpd.config file the root was set with a backslash like PHPIniDir "C:\php\" instead of normal slash like PHPIniDir "C:/php/"

Comment: To see the list of loaded modules/extensions go to the command line and type X:> php -m. Do you see the extensions mysqli and mbstring?

Comment: OK, i can see that these 2 extensions that you mention are in fact loaded. Try writing a small script with a call to a function in the mb_* family of functions and a call to mysql_* function and see the error log for details

Comment: Call `phpinfo()` and check the top section for what `php.ini` file is _actually_ being used – most likely you edited the wrong one.

Comment: .php file not found. But when i run index.php with<?php
echo "OK";
phpinfo();?> inside everything goes well

Comment: phpinfo()   I have this "-without-mssql" in Configure Command section. Can it be the problem?

Comment: @Jake. I think that the php.ini used is the same for cli and the apache module.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "php.ini used is the same for cli and the apache module" means :)

Comment: "Zend Multibyte Support  disabled" can be a problem for mbstring?

Comment: when I tried to connect to database I had "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\Apache\Apache24\htdocs\pma_test.php" error :(

Comment: in Configure Command section I have this: "--without-mssql" can it be a problem and, if it is, how can I fix it?

Comment: OK then, my bad. I knew about linux but i thought that on windows there is a single php.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say this:

> I uncommented mbstring in `php.ini`

Then you say you ran this in the command line:

> C:\php>php -m

Okay, first the second thing: Running `php` in the command line is not the same as running it as a module in Apache. Two 100% different things. So knowing that, are you sure you are editing the correct `php.ini` file?

To get a real feel for what your Apache PHP module is set to do, create a file called `phpinfo.php` in your web root and place the `phpinfo` command in it like this:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Then load that via a web browser. You should get a full list of what is installed & how PHP is configured. In the case of your `php.ini`, look for the line that says **Loaded Configuration File** which will tell you exactly which `php.ini` file is being loaded by the Apache PHP module. Below is a screenshot of my `phpinfo` output on MAMP running on Mac OS X; it looks similar on whatever system you run the command on.

[image]

Comment: Loaded Configuration File "C:\Windows\php.ini ".  But in C:\windows\ there is no php.ini file. I copied php.ini file from my php dyrectory to C:\windows, but it doesn't help. How can I change Loaded Configuration File's path?